# Assign values to variables in loop

Tags: javascript

I'm using the platform of Google Earth Engine.

I have my list of variables, and what i want is to assign each value of ***i*** to each variable

```
var Y03, Y04, Y05, Y06, Y07, Y08,Y09, Y10, Y11, Y12,Y13, Y14, Y15,Y16, Y17, Y18;

var Years = [ Y03, Y04, Y05, Y06, Y07, Y08,Y09, Y10, Y11, Y12,Y13, Y14, Y15,Y16, Y17, Y18];

for (var i = 2003; i <= 2018; i++){
  Years[i] = i; 
}
print(Y05); //undefined
```

As you can see, when i use ***print(Y05)***, the result is ***undefined*** and i want ***2005***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily assign values to variables using [Array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) like:

```js
var [Y03, Y04, Y05, Y06, Y07, Y08,Y09, Y10, Y11, Y12,Y13, Y14, Y15,Y16, Y17, Y18] 
  = Array.from({length: 16}, (x, i) => 2003 + i)

console.log( Y05 )
console.log( Y03, Y18 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not assign values to variable in this way.
If you print(Years) than you can see the updated values